# iOS dropbox api oauth_token error

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

For some purpose I have created singleton that organize all works with dropbox via this new object.

So I have next singleton with initialization code as below:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.cloudName = @"Dropbox";

        DBSession* dbSession = [[DBSession alloc] initWithAppKey:DP_App_KEY
                                                       appSecret:DP_App_SECRET
                                                            root:ROOT];

        [DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];

        self.restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
        self.restClient.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

If you can see I init DBSession directly in my singleton init method. The app call init method and seems everything should work good.

So when I logged in the app calls this in open url method:

```
if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked])
```

and app output here that the dropbox is linked, but when I try to to get metadata for root @"/" folder (list of files) and call this method:

```
[self.restClient loadMetadata:folder];
```

the app output this error:

```
[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/metadata/dropbox - (403) Parameter not found: oauth_token
2014-04-25 00:30:15.652 PDF-Notes[75257:70b] Error loading metadata: Error Domain=dropbox.com Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (dropbox.com error 403.)" UserInfo=0xb666600 {path=/, error=Parameter not found: oauth_token}
```

But when I rerun app via Xcode one more time everything works good. Also if I set `DBSession` in app delegate it also works. I really did not understand why it does not work in singleton because the invocation methods works in the same way, but only if we init `DBSession` in app it works without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - you have to create REST client only after session became linked - this will ensure you that DBRestClient will be connected to real session.

Second - problems can be if there are a Dropbox application installed on device with your application. In this case your application will push up the authentification to DB application.

And third - your implementation of - (id) init for your class is not a singleton. Singleton is a pattern when your object lives only in one common object and no recreation can be done. I Objective C we have to look after retain counts as well (in no-Arc code shode be overridden memory management methods). But in anyway your init method (often called shared instance) should look like that:

```
static Singleton * sharedInstance= nil;
+(Singleton *) sharedInstance
{

    static dispatch_once_t once_token = 0;
    dispatch_once(&once_token, ^
                  {
                      sharedInstance =  [Singleton  new];
                  });
    return sharedInstance ;
}
```

Hope this will help you with DB integration

Comment: yes, thank you. I also have repaired it by adding another way. At first I got session, then I initialize rest client, because in my question the rest client initialized with session that is not correspond to a valid or authorized one. Seems by lines it is ok but by invocation type it is wrong. I have skip the singleton initialization just and init method for demo problem.